# Javascript alert causes page content to disappear

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138.

When I try to open/refresh the html file I have with the following code, the page content does not appear until I click the OK button on the alert dialog. How can I fix this so that the content and the dialog are shown?

I have tried this on MS Edge as well with the same issue...

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Hello World!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hello, World!");
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `alert` blocks the execution, so ideally you wouldn't use `alert` at all for precisely this reason. It makes it hard to actually test stuff. Do you *really* need `alert`? If so, you'd have to wait until the page is loaded and then show it.

Comment: Wrapping it in a `setTimeout()` should do it, probably even with a delay of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Alert freezes the page by design. You could try modifying your code a bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert("Hello, World!");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you all for helping out!

I have tried the code modification/s here, without success.

I went back and tried running my original code shown in Firefox and it worked,
i.e., the page content was still visible behind the alert dialog with
the page just greyed out. The code also worked fine with Internet Explorer.

All the other browsers I have tried - Chrome, Edge, Opera have the content
blanking issue so I remain perplexed.

I am just beginning javascript, hence the simple code...

Sorry I was not better prepared before posting the question!

Comment: @GerryYates No worries!
Using `alert()` is not the best User Experience though. I probably wouldn't want to use it. Is it somewhat necessary for you?

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. The alert() function is part of the WebDev course I am studying, which is  just teaching very basic javascript at the moment - we are just starting to get into other ways of doing things in js now. My concern was that the mainstream browsers handle the alert() function differently.